# How to calculate Retail-MAC(Single DES Plus Final Triple DES MAC) in SCP02 (Secure channel Protocol 02) with ICV encryption?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have seen multiple people asking for a help on C-MAC generation(Retail MAC). This question contains the answer as well. 
This will help your enough time. 
I have tested this function with real card and it worked fine.

Comment: [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) is a different signature algorithm to the retail MAC which is used in SCP02. Please consider removing the `cmac` tag.

Comment: @vlp I have made changes in title of question. Thanks for suggestion. 
Would you please create tag for 'retail-mac'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**

1. One can improve the efficiency of function if like.
2. If you find any improvement please suggest.
3. Before you start work on SCP 02 with communication in Ext_Atuh as CMAC please check SCP i value.

   4. This function supports ICV encryption for next command.

public static byte[] generateCmac(byte []apdu,byte[]sMacSessionKey,byte[]icv) throws Exception {

```
    if(sMacSessionKey.length == 16) {
    byte []temp  = sMacSessionKey.clone();
    sMacSessionKey = new byte[24];
    System.arraycopy(temp,0,sMacSessionKey,0,temp.length);
    System.arraycopy(temp,0,sMacSessionKey,16,8);
    }

    byte []cMac = new byte[8];
    byte []padding = {(byte)0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,};
    int paddingRequired  = 8 - (apdu.length) %8;
    byte[] data = new byte[apdu.length + paddingRequired];
    System.arraycopy(apdu, 0, data, 0, apdu.length);
    System.arraycopy(padding, 0, data, apdu.length,paddingRequired);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");

            Cipher singleDesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding",
                "SunJCE");
            SecretKeySpec desSingleKey = new SecretKeySpec(sMacSessionKey, 0, 8,
                "DES");
            SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(sMacSessionKey, "DESede");
            // Calculate the first n - 1 block. For this case, n = 1
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(icv);
            singleDesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desSingleKey, ivSpec);
            // byte ivForLastBlock[] = singleDesCipher.doFinal(data, 0, 8);

            int blocks = data.length / 8;

            for (int i = 0; i < blocks - 1; i++) {
                singleDesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desSingleKey, ivSpec);
                byte[] block = singleDesCipher.doFinal(data, i * 8, 8);
                ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(block);
            }

            int offset = (blocks - 1) * 8;

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);
            cMac = cipher.doFinal(data, offset, 8);

            ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);

            singleDesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desSingleKey, ivSpec);
            icvNextCommand = singleDesCipher.doFinal(cMac);
            System.out.println("icvNextCommand"+Utility.bytesToHex(icvNextCommand, icvNextCommand.length));

            return cMac;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A way simpler alternative is to use `Signature.ALG_DES_MAC8_ISO9797_1_M2_ALG3` (if supported by the card) to calculate [retail MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9797-1#MAC_algorithm_3) value for C-MAC in SCP02.

Note: [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) is a message authentication code which is not used in SCP02 at all.

EDIT> For PC side consider [ISO9797Alg3Mac](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/macs/ISO9797Alg3Mac.java) from [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).